# removeFrom* not working and with no errors

Tags: grails

I have what I think is a simple problem but have been unable to solve... 
For some reason I have a controller that uses removeFrom*.save() which throws no errors but does not do anything.

Running 
Grails 1.2 
Linux/Ubuntu

The following application is stripped down to reproduce the problem...

I have two domain objects via create-domain-class 
- Job (which has many notes) 
- Note (which belongs to Job)

I have 3 controllers via create-controller 
- JobController (running scaffold) 
- NoteController (running scaffold) 
- JSONNoteController

JSONNoteController has one primary method deleteItem which aims to remove/delete a note.

It does the following

- some request validation
- removes the note from the job - jobInstance.removeFromNotes(noteInstance).save()
- deletes the note - noteInstance.delete()
- return a status and remaining data set as a json response.

When I run this request - I get no errors but it appears that jobInstance.removeFromNotes(noteInstance).save() does nothing and does not throw any exception etc. 
How can I track down why??

I've attached a sample application that adds some data via BootStrap.groovy. 
Just run it - you can view the data via the default scaffold views.

If you run linux, from a command line you can run the following 
GET "http://localhost:8080/gespm/JSONNote/deleteItem?job.id=1&note.id=2"

You can run it over and over again and nothing different happens. You could also paste the URL into your webbrowser if you're running windows.

Please help - I'm stuck!!!
Code is here [link text](http://old.nabble.com/file/p27255806/gespmtest.tar.gz)

Note Domain

```
package beachit

class Note
{

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    String note

    static belongsTo = Job

    static constraints =
    {
    }

    String toString()
    {
        return note
    }
}
```

Job Domain

```
package beachit

class Job
{

    Date dateCreated
    Date lastUpdated

    Date        createDate
    Date        startDate
    Date        completionDate

    List notes

    static hasMany = [notes : Note]

    static constraints =
    {
    }

    String toString()
    {
        return createDate.toString() + " " + startDate.toString();
    }
}
```

JSONNoteController

```
package beachit

import grails.converters.*
import java.text.*

class JSONNoteController
{

    def test = { render "foobar test"  }

    def index = { redirect(action:listAll,params:params) }

    // the delete, save and update actions only accept POST requests
    //static allowedMethods = [delete:'POST', save:'POST', update:'POST']

    def getListService =
    {
        def message
        def status
        def all = Note.list()

        return all
    }

    def getListByJobService(jobId)
    {
        def message
        def status

        def jobInstance = Job.get(jobId)
        def all

        if(jobInstance)
        {
            all = jobInstance.notes
        }
        else
        {
            log.debug("getListByJobService job not found for jobId " + jobId)
        }

        return all

    }

    def listAll =
    {
        def message
        def status
        def listView

        listView    = getListService()
        message     = "Done"
        status      = 0

        def response = ['message': message, 'status':status, 'list': listView]
        render response as JSON
    }

    def deleteItem =
    {
        def jobInstance
        def noteInstance
        def message
        def status
        def jobId = 0
        def noteId = 0
        def instance
        def listView
        def response

        try
        {
            jobId = Integer.parseInt(params.job?.id)
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException ex)
        {
            log.debug("deleteItem error in jobId " + params.job?.id)
            log.debug(ex.getMessage())
        }

        if (jobId && jobId > 0 )
        {
            jobInstance = Job.get(jobId)

            if(jobInstance)
            {
                if (jobInstance.notes)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        noteId = Integer.parseInt(params.note?.id)
                    }
                    catch (NumberFormatException ex)
                    {
                        log.debug("deleteItem error in noteId " + params.note?.id)
                        log.debug(ex.getMessage())
                    }

                    log.debug("note id =" + params.note.id)
                    if (noteId && noteId > 0 )
                    {
                        noteInstance = Note.get(noteId)
                        if (noteInstance)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                jobInstance.removeFromNotes(noteInstance).save()
                                noteInstance.delete()

                                message = "note ${noteId} deleted"
                                status = 0
                            }
                            catch(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e)
                            {
                                message = "Note ${noteId} could not be deleted - references to it exist"
                                status = 1
                            }
                            /*
                            catch(Exception e)
                            {
                                message = "Some New Error!!!"
                                status = 10
                            }
                            */
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            message = "Note not found with id ${noteId}"
                            status  = 2
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message = "Couldn't recognise Note id : ${params.note?.id}"
                        status = 3
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "No Notes found for Job : ${jobId}"
                    status = 4
                }
            }
            else
            {
                message = "Job not found with id ${jobId}"
                status = 5
            }

            listView    = getListByJobService(jobId)

        } // if (jobId)
        else
        {
            message = "Couldn't recognise Job id : ${params.job?.id}"
            status = 6
        }

        response = ['message': message, 'status':status, 'list' : listView]
        render response as JSON

    } // deleteNote
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help, but
Changing the save() and delete to save(flush:true) and delete(flush:true) is causing the following Exception on the delete() call: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)

Comment: I've also had some problems with removeFrom* in Grails 1.1.1 that I've never been able to figure out.

Comment: Interesting... the same code works in BootStrap.groovy but not in the controller. 
If there are no other comments I might just raise an issue in Jira.. I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this thread: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/GORM-doesn-t-inject-hashCode-and-equals-td1370512.html

I would recommend using a base class for your domain objects like this:

```
abstract class BaseDomain {

    @Override
    boolean equals(o) {
        if(this.is(o)) return true
        if(o == null) return false
        // hibernate creates dynamic subclasses, so 
        // checking o.class == class would fail most of the time
        if(!o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(getClass()) && 
            !getClass().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) return false

        if(ident() != null) {
            ident() == o.ident()
        } else {
            false
        }
    }

    @Override
    int hashCode() {
        ident()?.hashCode() ?: 0
    }

}
```

That way, any two objects with the same non-null database id will be considered equal.

Comment: I am confused by this; why would implementing equals/hashCode have anything to do with being able to remove an object from a collection?

Comment: @CharlesWood GORM doesn't implement equals and hashCode for you. So two instances of the same object (the instance returned by get(noteId) is a new instance) with the same id are not equal(), so nothing is removed from the collection.

Answer (score 5):

I got it working... though  I cannot explain why.

I replaced the following line in deleteItem

```
noteInstance = Note.get(noteId)
```

with the following

```
noteInstance = jobInstance.notes.find { it.id == noteId }
```

For some reason the jobInstance.removeFromNotes works with the object returned by that method instead of .get
What makes it stranger is that all other gorm functions (not sure about the dynamic ones actually) work against the noteInstance.get(noteId) method.

At least it's working though!!

Comment: It seems the way the grails itself suggest to delete items from a domain collection. See: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html

Comment: Is not working for me in `Grails 4.0.11`   1. `def row = AirlineOfferFullFreighter.get(data.id)` 2. `def bid = row.bids.find{ it.user == springSecurityService.currentUser }`  3. `row.removeFromBids(bid)`  4. `row.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)`  -> without `bid.delete()` the delete is not persisted. I'm using MySQL btw.

Answer (score 4):

I just had this same issue come up.  The removeFrom function succeeded, the save succeeded but the physical record in the database wasn't deleted.  Here's what worked for me:

```
  class BasicProfile {
        static hasMany = [
                post:Post
        ]
    }

    class Post {
       static belongsTo = [basicProfile:BasicProfile]
    }

    class BasicProfileController {
        ...

def someFunction
    ...   
        BasicProfile profile = BasicProfile.findByUser(user)

           Post post = profile.post?.find{it.postType == command.postType && it.postStatus == command.postStatus}

       if (post) {
          profile.removeFromPost(post)
          post.delete()
       }
       profile.save()

    }
```

So it was the combination of the removeFrom, followed by a delete on the associated domain, and then a save on the domain object.

Comment: I, too, found that the delete() call was needed, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Yep, without `delete()` it doesn't work either for me in Grails 3. I assumed `removeFrom()` was enough to delete.

Comment: Need to do a 'row.delete()` as well in `Grails 4.0.11`