# Grails/Groovy isn't persisting change in object's collection

Tags: grails, groovy, persistence

I have the following problem:

My object route contains a list of routepoints. When I alter this list, the changed list is saved. But when the next method accesses the list, it seems like the change reverted. I ruled some kind of transaction rollback out, b/c on the end of the altering method, i acces the list by loading it from the database and it still has the right (altered) size. Here's the code:

First the altering method:

```
def removeStationFromRoute(station){
    def driver = Driver.get(Integer.valueOf(requestAccessService.getParams().userId))
    def route = driver.routes.find{
        it.routeDate == new Date().clearTime()
    }
    def rp = Routepoint.findByStation(station)

    route.routepoints.remove(rp)

    def newRoute = driver.routes.find{ it.routeDate == new Date().clearTime()}
    println 'new route size: ' + newRoute.routepoints.size()

    def newRoute2 = Route.get(route.id)
    println 'new route from db size: ' + newRoute2.routepoints.size()

}
```

Both prints return a size of 5, which is correct. Right after this method is carried out, this method is executed:

```
def getDriverRoute(){
    def driver = User.get(Long.valueOf(params.userId))
    def route = driver.routes.find{ it.routeDate == new Date().clearTime()}
    println 'serialized route size: ' + route.routepoints.size()
    def routeString = jobService.serializeRoute(route)
    log.info('Route with ' + route.routepoints.size() + " stations serialized for User " + driver.encodeAsHTML())
    render routeString
}
```

Which prints a size of 6, as if no change happened to the list. I already tried saving the driver, the route and the routepoint after the change is made in the "removeStationFromRoute"-List, as well as checking the three objects for errors. Didn't help.

Thanks for any ideas what to do!

Comment: Is that a typo in the second method where the driver is User.get instead of Driver.get?

Comment: Nope, Driver is a subclass of User, but I changed it to Driver.get() in both methods and it still won't work

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a 1-N relationship between `Route` and `Routepoints`? Something like

```
class Route {
  static hasMany = [routepoints: Routepoint]
}

class Routepoint {
  static belongsTo = [route: Route]
}
```

You **should not** add/remove routpoints using the `add`/`remove` methods of the `Collection` interface. Instead you should use the `addTo*`/`removeFrom*` GORM methods, e.g.

```
route.addToRoutepoints(routepoint)
route.removeFromRoutepoints(routepoint)
```

Comment: Changed it, but I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
After you have used `route.removeFromRoutepoints(routepoint)`
to remove the mapping of the Routepoint with Route in the first method, the Route Object Still needs to be persisted using `.save/.merge` method.(Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19017946/2889156) )

Secondly. 
In hibernate, using Domain.get(id) will not always hit the Database, IF the object already cached in the Hibernate session. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608947/hibernate-difference-between-session-get-and-session-load)

Hope it helps...